# UNIX: variable inside variable

Tags: unix

I just try to put variable inside variable but it doesn't work... How can i Fix it?

```
DEL=$(find . -type f | sed "s/^.*\///g" | sed -n '/\./p' | sed "s/.*\.//g" | uniq)
EL=$(${DEL} | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
```

Comment: try `EL=$(echo ${DEL} | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')`

Comment: well... it prints something, but still it doesn't put comma between space. :)

Comment: @user3463055 `echo ${DEL}` prints all elements on a line, that's why tr can't replace `'\n'` with `','`. I think you can workout what you need on your own, besides you didn't mention the desired output in your question. :)

Comment: I want to print all file extensions and between spaces I need to put commas... But thank you for your reply, I have already found a solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
EL=$(tr '\n' ',' <<< "$DEL" | sed 's/,$//')
```

or

```
EL=$(echo "$DEL" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
```

Comment: The first will work.  The second would work if you use `echo "$DEL"` but as written (without double quotes), there'd be just one newline in the input to `tr`, right at the end, and the `sed` would remove the one comma that `tr` adds (which is really not very productive).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thanks for pointing this out, I have modified it.

Comment: YW: I should also have noted that the shell must be Bash (or a shell that supports here-strings with `<<<` — POSIX shells don't support that).  The second works with most shells.